# % of grand total for one value in a column grouped by date and date range in DAX

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, percentage

I am attempting to create a DAX measure that will calculate the % of a specific value in a column grouped by a specific date or date range.

Here is how my current data is structured:

[image]

For example, if I want the see % of bagels sold for a single day (say August 1st), the base total of all items of would be for that day (4) rather than the total sales for the entire table (16) and I would want to display the % of bagels for that day (50%), like so:

[image]

But, if I want to see the % of bagels for all transactions between 8-1 and 8-3, that base total would be 16 and the % of bagels would be 31.25%.

[image]

I have the follow DAX formula to calculate the % of bagels for the entire table.

Measure =
DIVIDE(
CALCULATE(
COUNT('Table'[Transaction ID]),
FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Item] = "Bagel")
),
CALCULATE(
COUNT('Table'[Transaction ID]),
ALL('Table'[Item])
),
0
)

What I'm not sure of is how to create a measure that calculates % of bagels based on the count of all items sold within a specific date or date range column so that I can connect it to a date range slicer like this one:

[image]

...So that when the user selects 8-1 the visual will display 50% and if the user selects 8-1 to 8-3 the visual will display 31.25%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a Slicer visual and use the Date as the slicer's field. Make sure the following are selected:

1. Slicer type is "Between";
2. Date column is formatted as date type;

When you create the table with Item and Measure as fields, it should work.

[image: Only 08/01]

[image: 08/01 through 08/03]

Comment: You're correct, all I needed was a slicer. I was assuming my numbers were not calculating correctly because my % did not match the business team's %. Turns out mine is accurate based on the data model!